# get error on android device after run "react-native run-android" command

Tags: android, react-native

this is my cmd after run react-native run-android : https://up.20script.ir/file/2412-Capture2.jpg
.
and this is my phone screen after that : https://up.20script.ir/file/2412-Screenshot-2018-08-17-13-38-38.png
.
and this in my package.json detail :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
```

, What am i going to do ?

Comment: This is common issue for windows computer with `"react-native": "0.56.0"` change version to 0.55.4 in package.json, delete node modules folder, then `yarn install `

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened after adding dependency via npm after generating the react-native init project.

just try the below steps:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf yarn.lock
rm -rf package-lock.json
```

then `npm install`.

As I understood you are using windows, simply delete the above mentioned file and folder.

If it will not work, please comment.